# I can't open .txt or csv file

Tags: python

[Trying to open file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLdRL.png)

I'm learning python as my first programing language and i've been trying to open this .txt file and it says that can't find it

-Tried to specify as much de file direction (besides being in the same folder)
-Tried deleting the files and coding everything again

Comment: My wild guess (in the absence of enough information to do anything other than make a wild guess) is your path should be `"Curso de dalto\\archivos\\texto_de_dalto.txt`" instead of `"archivos\\texto_de_dalto.txt"`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking to an image, please edit your post and type out the code and error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future questions, please provide the code in the question as text (attaching a screenshot is fine but make sure to add the code either in the question or a pastebin link)

The problem is your working directory is set to the `Curso Python folder` and not `Curso Python folder/Curso de dalto` which actually contains the folder and file you are trying to open.

The path of the file you specified is a [relative path](https://www.codingrooms.com/blog/file-paths#:%7E:text=A%20relative%20path%20describes%20the,regularly%20use%20relative%20file%20paths.) which means it's your current working directory + the path you specified.

When running a python script, the directory you run it from is set as the default working directory. If you change your directory in the terminal using `cd Curso de dalto` and then run the code it should run.

Another tip, you can always check the current working directory in python using:

```python
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```